# Determination of angle of deviation and rotation of the vector

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I'm sorry for my drawing skills and mistakes in grammar.

I'm trying to solve next task:

Phone is somehow fixed in a phoneholder in a car. As it is displayed on picture. Purple - car coordinate system, red - phone's one.

```
X - perpendicular to the movement and parallel to the ground
Y - parallel to the movement and to the ground
Z - perpendicular to the ground
```

During the calibration phase I can assume, that all measured acceleration belongs to single axis - Y. So I have two vectors:

```
Measured acceleration (ma) - [x, y, z]
Expected acceleration (ea) - [0, |ma|, 0]
```

How can I calculate rotation matrix, angles or something else I don't know about, to transform measured (phone) acceleration to expected (car)?

[image: example]

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: You have enough information to determine the true $Y$-axis direction, but not enough to determine which way is “up.”